# how to read sql query output in python

Tags: python, sqlplus

I am using sqlplus in my Python code to connect to data base and executing the query and reading the results. Can any one help me how to read the data from sysout.

My Code is Like this:

```
    stdout = os.popen(cmd)
for line in stdout:
    print line
stdout.close()
```

But I could see the result as for every three rows title is repeating like:

```
Name               ID

----               ---

AB                 1

AC                 2

AD                 3

Name               ID

----               ---

BC                 1

BD                 2
```

like this.

Is it possible to control this, with out repeating the header, header should come only once and it should come only in the beginning.

Comment: I don't quite understand what all that is. Which are the column titles, which are the values ?

Comment: Name, ID are the columns in that table

Comment: can you post your query ?

Comment: select Name, Id from NameTable;

Comment: if you run sqlplus alone, do you have the same output ? if so, can you not simply skip 2 lines every 5 ?

Comment: yes it is giving same as above even if I run sqlplus alone. Yes, if there is no option avaiable, then I have to do in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing:

- Launching a standalone program which queries the database and prints the results to stdout
- Reading the stdout of that program and thinking about parsing it.

What you should be doing:

- Using a database API in Python.

This page contains a list of Oracle DB APIs you could use: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle

Many benefits will come from using a real API to query the database, such as better opportunities to handle errors, probably better performance, and future maintainers of your code not being upset with you.

Comment: Yes I do agree, but there are some limitation for us in using those, so we are using sqlplus.

Comment: What limitations are those?  Perhaps we can solve that problem.

Comment: We can achieve the expected behavior with sqlplus, so it is not recommended to install others, we need to prove them that it cant be achieved with sqlplus, then after required approvals only they will install. I believe we can achieve the same with sqlplus, and it has happen earlier when we proposed.

Comment: In that case, does your version of sqlplus have the "-MARKUP HTML ON" option as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm ?  If so, please turn it on and see if you can parse the output using Python's lxml/ElementTree or BeautifulSoup HTML parsers.